# Can I know webfont useage rates?

Tags: webfonts

I'm creating wiki about webfont usage+optimization. 
In process, I need numeric data that present webfont usage graph from specific year to now(2018). How can I get this material?

In the process of Google, I find https://httparchive.org 's Sites with custom fonts data which is what I want.

[enter image description here][1]

I've accessed the site, but I can't find custom font category. Is there something I can't find?? or Where can I find material.

Answer (score 0):

Getting stats for a webfont provider such as google fonts might give you better data. because webfonts can be self or used in different ways it would be hard to get true figures or general webfont usage.

Google publish stats on their webfont service such as [This overall stats table](https://www.google.com/fonts/stats?key=WebFonts2010)
(i.e. Roboto used 58,863,790,914 times this week!!)

Built with also provide stats on [google webfont based sites here](https://trends.builtwith.com/widgets/Google-Font-API)

this article on [webfont performance](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/web-font-performance) might also help